# How do screen readers read <abbr> tags?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, abbr

I learned that the `<abbr>` tag is supposed to be interpreted by screen readers in a way that its `title` attribute would replace its content when read by a screen reader. However, when I try that, neither MacOS (Firefox and Safari) Voiceover nor NVDA (Windows 10, Edge and Firefox) work that way. Here's the relevant code part:

```
... bla bla bla <abbr title="nervus">N.</abbr> peronaeus ...
```

(that's a medical expression)

IMO this should be read as "... bla bla bla nervus peronaeus ...", but it's read as "... bla bla bla N.", then a long silence (or the screen reader even stops before it), apparently because of the dot, and then "peronaeus ..." - no "nervus"...

Am I using the syntax correctly or is there something which I am missing? Or, if that's correct: Is there any WAI-ARIA code or similar which I could add to make it work the way it's suppposed to be on most screen readers?

Comment: You are using the syntax absolutely correctly. But where did you read that screen readers are supposed to pronounce the title rather than the contents?

Comment: I didn't read it, I was told that in a course I took - apparently not so good...

Answer (score 6):

You can't really depend on the user hearing the `title` attribute of the element. [Here's a good resource on how screen readers process HTML elements](https://thepaciellogroup.github.io/AT-browser-tests/), and for `abbr`, the entry is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, screen readers usually just read out the element content. Since `N.` contains a period, it just reads out "N", then does a full stop for the period. You can set up the screen reader to read the `title` content, but it's an opt-in setting, so you shouldn't depend on it. There's really no way to set content for a screen reader with `title`.

Comment: Thank's for that info - that page is a very good resource, I didn't know it before

Comment: @Johannes I really don't see a way to actually make the screen reader read the `title` of an `abbr`. A screen reader would read it if it's explicitly set as a preference. The only way I'd see it reading would be to just spell out word.

Comment: Well, I am thinking about `span` tags with different attributes/CSS styles (one invisible to, the other "visible" *only*  to screen readers), but somehow this seems to interrupt the reading flow and be treated as seperate phrases (i.e. stopping at the tag borders), although in theory an inline element like `span` shouldn't act like that. in addition, this is inside a list item and the spans are announced as additional items in the list... I guess I'd have to use different phrasing, but I am not supposed to change the text of my client...

Comment: This page has good stats on screen reader support (about 71% as of Dec 27/2017): https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/acronym-abbr-title/

Answer (score 3):

The `abbr` tag is just misleading.

In your case, you do not want to give information to blind users only but to people ignoring what appears to be a common medical abbreviated term. A non blind user, not using a screenreader, needs this information.

On the contrary, blind people using braille displays do enjoy abbreviations. A lot.

---

If you want a very effective way to handle abbreviation, use a glossary :

```
 <a href="/glossary/nervus-peronaeus"
        aria-label="Nervus peronaeus"
        title="Nervus peronaeus" class="glossary">N. Peronaeus</a>
```

The `aria-label` has very good support on links, and the `title` attribute may be used to give a hint to non-screenreader users.

The glossary may be inserted inside the page in the bottom for instance.

```
 <a href="#nervus-peronaeus"
        aria-label="Nervus peronaeus"
        title="Nervus peronaeus" class="glossary">N. Peronaeus</a>
```

My preferred way to handle abbreviations is not using them.

```
Nervus Peronaeus
```

Clear. Concise. That seems maybe trivial but when you think an abbreviation deserves an explanation, that's the best way for everyone (motor, visual, cognitive disabilities).

Of course, for abbreviations part of the language you do not need to explain them (FBI, NATO, ...). In a medical website for professionals only the "N. peronaeus" term maybe part of the language for the targeted public.

Comment: I agree in general with all this, but there may be situations where <abbr> is appropriate. In that case I suggest using both the title and aria-label attributes, but only on the first instance on a page. `<abbr title="Operating System" aria-label="Operating System">OS</a>`

Comment: Be careful as screenreaders rarely interpret `aria-label` on non interactive elements. Blind people do like abbreviations (especially welcomed when they use braille display) and do not want to be explained systematically well known abbreviations (like "OS" which is more used and understandable than "operating system")

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Use the complete term plus the abbreviation in brackets on the first instance on a page, and then just the abbreviation thereafter. Wikipedia: "Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) is the standard markup language for creating web pages and web applications." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

Answer (score 0):

I found the best supported way to have screenreaders read out acronyms is by inserting zero-width spaces with the code `&#8203;. E.g. A&#8203;B&#8203;C` is announced as "A B C" but displays as "ABC". Note that browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Edge) all FIND "ABC" so this technique does not destroy other functionality.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you for sharing it! But I was actually not talking about acronyms, but about abbreviations inside <abbr> tags, where I would have expected screen readers to read the full word (i.e. the value of the 'title' attribute of the tag) instead of the abbreviation/s.

Comment: That's an interesting idea but you would have to test it with a braille device to make sure the `&#8203;` doesn't read as an actual character.