# Is it necessary to include aria-label for <abbr>?

Tags: wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers, abbreviation

I am currently learning about developing for accessibility and I'm going down the list of tags.

When using abbreviations, I would normally type:

```
<abbr full="As Soon as Possible">ASAP</abbr>
```

For VoiceOver, it reads the full-attribute (not sure about the other screen readers).

Is it necessary to include aria-label for this case? I know that the full-attribute would be ignored since the aria-label is present, but is it good practice to have it? Or is it overkill?

```
<abbr aria-label="As Soon as Possible" full="As Soon as Possible">ASAP</abbr>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I asked a related question a while ago and got some interesting answers and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45776312/5641669

Comment: @Johannes Thanks :)!